# K Fold Cross Validation in in KNN algorithm

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, k-nearest-neighbour

I have a dataset with 2000, observations and 21 columns. Using KNN, I want to classify validating data using last column `price_range` which contains the `factors "0,"1","2","3"`.

I want to improve my model using K Fold cross validation. Here's my code.

```
train_control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number=10)
set.seed(333)
knn_fit <- train(price_range~., method="knn", tuneLength = 10, metric ="Accuracy",trControl=train_control, data = mp, preProcess = c("center","scale"))
```

Result of `knn_fit`

```
k-Nearest Neighbors 

2000 samples
  20 predictor
   4 classes: '0', '1', '2', '3' 

Pre-processing: centered (20), scaled (20) 
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 1 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 1800, 1800, 1800, 1800, 1800, 1800, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  k   Accuracy  Kappa    
   5  0.5050    0.3400000
   7  0.5265    0.3686667
   9  0.5420    0.3893333
  11  0.5555    0.4073333
  13  0.5710    0.4280000
  15  0.5745    0.4326667
  17  0.5930    0.4573333
  19  0.5985    0.4646667
  21  0.6055    0.4740000
  23  0.6205    0.4940000

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final value used for the model was k = 23.
```

I was using this [example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/318968/knn-and-k-folding-in-r) and the Accuracy of their model is ranging from 0.95 to 0.96. Mine is around 0.5.

How do I improve my model so that the accuracy is higher?